# Extremely annoying cursor issue in pgadmin4 ver 3

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

After moving to pgadmin4 ver3 from the prior version I am no longer able to see my cursor when editing text in the query window.

I can highlight text but If I move anywhere within the text line the cursor does not appear. It sometimes will appear at the end of the line but as soon as I left-arrow it disappears again.

I tried everything I can think of to resolve this but to no avail.  Even reinstalled from scratch.

I know it’s not a browser issue because I can click on the browser address line and left-arrow and the cursor is visible there. This only happen in pgadmin.

Is anyone else having this issue? And does anyone have a solution for this?

[image: Missing cursor]

Comment: Firstly, that doesn't look like my "Query Tool" window that I get by right click on the database. However I can see my cursor in the window you posted on my Win 10 + Chrome, as well as in the Query Tool window of course

Comment: What is your Chrome version? I suspect it's due to incompatibility of older chrome version.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) with Windows 10 on a new Dell Inspiron.

Comment: Thats the same Chrome as me, Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit). Are you opening the "Query Tool" window that I get by right click on the database?

Comment: Yep, right clicking on the table in the browser column to open the query window.  I've also removed all extensions in chrome. Still same results.

Comment: There's now a PGadmin Version 3.1 just out, give the new version a try

Comment: Slumdog, thanks for letting me know of the newer version but unfortunately there was no change after installing it. 
Very strange that this is only happening in THIS program and not anywhere else. Also strange that it doesn’t appear to be an issue  for others.

Comment: I should also state that the cursor appears just fine on every other window and editable field tried in PGadmin4 v3.1 such as a table properties comments or name fields. Just not the query window!  
I also set it in Preferences to open in a new browser tab – and still same issue. What a mystery.

Comment: Indeed. So does that gisdatabase of yours work fine on some other sql client like Squirrel? It's not the database causing the issue is it?

Comment: No, it's not the database. I've been working in other databases on other servers within PGadmin and the issue is the same. I haven't tried other management programs.  So very bizarre that is works in every other place except the query window.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue, it's working fine on both of my systems macOS & Win10 Pro.

Comment: I recently developed the same problem after using PgAdmin 4 without difficulty for months. As of today (8/13/2018), the problem persists with Google Chrome browser, but (for me), is resolved using MS Edge browser.

Comment: Well, I'm not the only one in the world with this issue then.  Off to ask how to use pgadmin 4 in edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a browser issue, at least in Chrome I could reproduce the disappearing cursor and get it working again.

The browser zoom level is the cause. Changing the zoom level of your browser should resolve. In my case, a zoom level of 90% caused the cursor to disappear as indicated in the question. Any other zoom level works fine.

Comment: Bob, You are absolutely correct!!! I can't believe I have been dealing with this issue all this time and it was just because my Chrome zoom was set to 90%. As you stated it works fine on any other zoom setting.

Comment: Took me at least as long, until a colleague casually indicated to check my zoom level. Drove me nuts.

Comment: Thank You, 
If the zoom level is set to 90% cursor stops showing but, lower zoom level (i.e <90%) shows the cursor as well as do higher zoom levels (>90%). The problem occurs in exactly 90% zoom in google chrome.

Comment: Great! You are correct. My zoom level was 90% and it causes a problem. Now it working after reset my browser zoom level. Thanks.